# Nested JPA Criteria Query with GroupBy and Max

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-criteria

I would like to query a table using Criteria Query in JPA Spring boot for the following sql:

```
SELECT p.id, p.spending, ms.maxspending from person p
INNER JOIN (SELECT p.id, max(p.spending) from person as ms GROUP BY p.id)
ON p.id = ms.id;
```

the table I want to derive from should look as follow: [image]
I have no issue joining values from different tables (entities) but I can't find a way to produce the sql I show above when there is a nested SELECT clause.... any help is greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Object[]> criteria = builder.createQuery(Object[].class);

Root<Person> root = criteria.from(Person.class);

// Create a subquery to get the maximum spending for each Person
Subquery<Integer> subquery = criteria.subquery(Integer.class);
Root<Person> subRoot = subquery.from(Person.class);

subquery.select(builder.max(subRoot.get("spending"))).groupBy(subRoot.get("id"));

// Select the id, spending, and maximum spending for each person
criteria.multiselect(root.get("id"), root.get("spending"), 
builder.greatest(root.get("spending")));

// Join the table with the subquery on the id
criteria.where(builder.equal(root.get("id"), subRoot.get("id")));

List<Object[]> results = entityManager.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
```

`Note:` The above JPA criteria might not directly work for you. You might need to make necessary changes according to your need